# ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following, which doesn't work, my validation seems that it's not triggered on the form submit.

```
<script src="/Public/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.13.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Public/javascript/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Public/javascript/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

......

<form action="/Controller/Action" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="bla();" data-ajax-method="POST" id="MyAjaxForm" method="post">    

.........

<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The x field is required." id="ViewModel_x" name="ViewModel.x" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ViewModel.x" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

.........

<a href="#" id="saveButton" onclick="$('#MyAjaxForm').submit();">Some button text</a>

</form>
```

Do you see something wrong in the generated markup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you see something wrong in the generated markup?

Yes, you seem to have forgotten to include the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script which is what interprets the HTML5 `data-*` validation attributes on your input fields and emits `jquery.validate` rules:

```
<script src="/Public/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.13.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Public/javascript/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Public/javascript/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Public/javascript/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: True, I missed that script. Thank you for spotting it. Still doesn't work, though...

Comment: I think you will need to provide a concise and yet complete example allowing me to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The problem was that there is a partial view getting loaded dynamically via ajax.actionlink and the validation didn't work. It works by calling some validationparse method.